# Where should I create an Exception object?

Tags: c#

The [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions) document on MSDN says that you can have an exception builder method inside your class if the same exception is to be used in many parts of the class. But also, it says that in some cases, it's better to use the exception's constructor.

Let's say I have the following code in an `UserData` class:

```cs
private MailAddress _addr;

public UserData(string emailAddress)
{
    // Tries to validate the e-mail address
    try
    {
        _addr = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(emailAddress), "Invalid email address.");
    }
    if (_addr.Address != emailAddress)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(emailAddress), "Invalid email address.");
    }
}
```

You can see that in both `throw` statements, I'm throwing the exact same exception.

The question is: Is it correct to add an exception builder method to get my exception and throw that? Will I get the correct stacktrace and such if I do so? And if not, how do I determine between exception builders and constructors?

Comment: The stacktrace will be correct because it depends on where you throw the exception, not where you create the instance.

Comment: Why do you even have `if (_addr.Address != emailAddress)` in your code anyways?

Comment: The majority of code I've seen is exactly as you have written in your example.  The concept of an exception builder is valid, if your exceptions are complicated, but in majority of cases, it's as simple as you have already shown.  I would keep doing that.

Comment: I would think that as long as it simplifies your code, do it. Duplicate descriptions doesn't necessarily mean a builder method would be simpler though. It's the same number of lines. IMO that section in the docs isn't super illustrative as far as how it's useful. I wouldn't bother, with your example.

Comment: I would use a guard clause to check if emailAddress is filled. Then I would rename the Method to something like ValidateEmailAdd or something. And when an exception is thrown inside new MailAddress you'll loose that callstack.

Comment: @user743414 What do you mean you'll lose the callstack?

Comment: @mason There will be every exception caught which is thrown inside new MailAddress(..) and a new one will be created, with a new callstack pointing to throw new ArgumentException(nameof(..)). So with this code every exception thrown by new MailAddress(..) will be loosed and therefore the callstack of that exception.

Comment: @user743414 Well thank goodness inner exceptions are a thing and can solve the very problem you're describing, so it's really a non-issue.

Comment: @mason But he doesn't use them. So the code we're seeing here has that issue. :)

Comment: @user743414 It's not necessary to use here. The exception from parsing the email address is pretty much going to only mean one thing: the email address wasn't in a valid format. So catching it and setting it as an inner exception isn't all that important, though one could make an argument the try/catch could be eliminated completely and the behavior would be close to the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to add an exception builder method to get my exception and throw that

That depends. As suggested in the article you linked: If it's the same exception (with the same information), it makes sense to create such a helper method to keep your code clean.

> Will I get the correct stacktrace and such if I do so

Yes, you will.
Take a look at this example. [(DotNetFiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rjJKBQ).

```
public static void Main() 
{
    try{
        throw CreateEx("Hi");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());   
    }

    try {
        CreateEx2("Hi");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); 
    }  

}

public static Exception CreateEx(string text){
    text += " Additional text";

    return new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(text);
}

public static void CreateEx2(string text){
    text += " Additional text";

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(text);
}
```

The stacktrace depends on where the exception is *thrown*, not where it is built.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Hi Additional text
   at Program.Main() in d:\Windows\Temp\b4ln3dbq.0.cs:line 13
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Hi Additional text
   at Program.CreateEx2(String text) in d:\Windows\Temp\b4ln3dbq.0.cs:line 34
   at Program.Main() in d:\Windows\Temp\b4ln3dbq.0.cs:line 19
```

Comment: But your example doesn't do what he does. He throws a new exception in the catch block.

Comment: @user743414 The same rules apply.